# Constructor Dependency Injection in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to do a dependency injection in my controller, instead using setters methods, but it didnot work.

What I want: just bind the domain model with my form, in a controller class using springframework 3.1.

My domain class:

```
public class Person {

  private String name;

  @Autowired
  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

}
```

My jsp(person-get):

```
<form action="test-person" method="post">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td> <b> NAME: </b> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

@RequestMapping(value = "test-person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadViewGet() {       
    return "person-get";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "test-person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doPost(Person person, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("person", person);

    return "person-post";
}

}
```

And the last jsp showing the entered name of the person by the user (person-post):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td> <b> NAME: </b> </td>
        <td> ${person.name} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The throwed exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: models.Person.<init>()
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttri    bute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodPr    ocessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgu    ment(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:103)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resol    veArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValu    es(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(Invo    cableHandlerMethod.java:117)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod    .invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.    invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.    handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(Abst    ractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java    :923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:    852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.ja    va:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
br.gov.sp.mococa.filtros.FiltroDeConexao.doFilter(FiltroDeConexao.java:31)
```

I think that the spring is looking for a default constructor whitout parameters. Why it is hapenning?

Thanks!

Comment: Where and how did you declare your Person bean in ApplicationContext?

Comment: Problem is you don't have a no-arg constructor (`public Person() {`, which is what the framework is trying to invoke) defined. Also why are you autowiring `name` in `Person`? You should just be passing a value while defining the bean.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the atention! So, that's the problem: if I place a default constructor, the framework use the setter way for the dependency injection, and I want use the constructor injection way. I know that has a way to do this, but dont know how. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For constructor injection you need to declare your bean as a spring bean in your spring-context or with an annotation.

However I doubt that it will pass a parameter as a constructor when used as a formbean. Spring should set the parameters with the setters. Use a standard constructor and add a setter.

Comment: "For constructor injection you need to declare your bean as a spring bean in your spring-context or with an annotation."

Answer (score 0):

spring creates objects using reflection which require default constructor. here u have created a parameterized constructor, hence default constructor is not available. so provide default constructor

Comment: I do that, but I cannot set the attribute value passed from the POST data to my model - I think the Spring MVC use reflection with the setter methods to do that. What should I do now? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that dependency injection is what you want?
Your code look more like you want constructor based form binding.

In the later case maybe the `@ModelAttribute` annotation can help you a bit.

For creating a model attribute based on request parameters you can use the `@ModelAttribute` annotation:

```
@ModelAttribute
public Person addPerson(@RequestParam String name) {
    return new Person(name);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "test-person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doPost(Model model) {
    // model already contains "person"
    return "person-post";
}
```

You can also receive model values in `RequestMapping` methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test-person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doPost(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, Model model) {
    // do someting with person..    
    return "person-post";
}
```

See [Using @ModelAttribute on a method argument](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) and [Using @ModelAttribute on a method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the attention! So, i've made the both ways you sow me, and doesnot works. HTTP ERROR 400.

Comment: About the dependency injection, I refer the internal DI of spring MVC - it pass the object person with DI, I'm right?

Comment: Finishing, u r right, I'm trying to bind a form with my domain. Use the setter way, can harm the business of my object - not in this simply case, but in anothers can. Is this what about I'm worried.