# Bind of the model with view in POST with Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to do a dependency injection in my controller, instead using setters methods, but it didnot work. The purpose is bind the form inputs with attributes of my domain model when do the post of the data form - with the controller.

What I want: just bind the domain model with my form, in a controller class using springframework 3.1.

My domain class:

```
public class Person {

  private String name;

  @Autowired
  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

}
```

My jsp(person-get):

```
<form action="test-person" method="post">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
      <td> <b> NAME: </b> </td>
      <td> <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

@RequestMapping(value = "test-person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadViewGet() {       
  return "person-get";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "test-person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doPost(Person person, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("person", person);

    return "person-post";
    }

}
```

And the last jsp showing the entered name of the person by the user (person-post):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td> <b> NAME: </b> </td>
    <td> ${person.name} </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There's a way to bind the form inputs with my my model class (Person) without using setter methods?

Anyone knows another web framework for java that could make this?

Thanks!

Comment: "instead using setters methods, but it did not work" How did it not work?

Comment: Throws a exception explaining that the attribute do not exists. The Spring MVC uses reflection in setter methods to do that. I wanna know if there's another way - without using setter methods - do do that. Thanks!

Comment: Now I see that this question is just a duplicate of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220310/constructor-dependency-injection-in-spring-mvc-3.

Comment: Yeah, I placed it in a wrong tag - Java instead Spring MVC. I'm gonna contact administrator to remove the previous. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` annotations and dependency injection is supported for beans created by application context's bean factory (beans defined in application context XML or `@Configuration` beans).

MVC's domain model objects are created during the request data binding process by handler argument resolvers (not by *application context*). Autowiring and other DI features are not supported. You **must user property accessors** (getters and setters) for your domain model objects.

Comment: I must? So, that's the only way to do that?

Comment: And the DDD? I need to have anemic objects because the Spring MVC works that way? If there's no choice, I'm gonna find another framework that dont force me to do this - using FIELD reflection instead method reflection. I'm also building a little framework by myself, lets see what will be. Thank so much by the explanation!

Comment: Spring is highly customisable... feel free to write your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. Then you will need to do the binding yourself. Is it only about the fact that Spring's data binding is based on property accessors?

Comment: Yeah, just about this. This harms the business of models - in some little projects that I have here, I cannot let a setter method for a object, because this would cause a inconsistence state of it if a programmer use the setter instead the correct method.

Comment: I dont understood about HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. I'm not so expert in Spring MVC, just have a good knowing about it. Can you explain me a little more about it? Thank you so much, again!

Comment: So in short you want your domain model objects to be *immutable*. That is fine. There are multiple ways how to do that and the most simple is if you will not use your domain objects in binding process. You are not forced to bind directly to your domain objects. Use special form beans for the binding and map to your domain model later in the handler method. You can also use Spring validation this way.

Comment: If you want to go through `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` check some tutorials. I am not able to cover the whole topic here.

Comment: I dont wanna have immutable objetcs, just wanna know if there's a way to bind the model and view without the setter method in Spring MVC. I'm gonna check the HandlerMethodArgumentResolve, as you said. Thank you again!

Comment: When I said "I dont wanna have immutable objetcs", just imagine that I want that my objetcts states changes only with my methods in objects - methods that make sense to the business of my domains - and not with setters that can harm the state of them.